# How can I execute a stored procedure with JPA & Spring Data?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to call the `Terminal_GetTicket` stored procedure in my database but keep getting the following exception:

```
PropertyReferenceException: No property getTicket found for type TicketInfo
```

I have cross validated my configuration with a very simple test entity and everything seems to work fine, however for the actual case, something is wrong.

Here is my domain entity (`TicketInfo`):

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "TicketInfo.getTicket", procedureName = "Terminal_GetTicket", resultClasses = TicketInfo.class, parameters = { 
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "sys_id_game", type = Integer.class)})
public class TicketInfo {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String idTicket;
    private Integer externalTicketCode;
    private Short sequenseAlert;
    private Integer dlTimeStamp;
```

All the instance variables have their getters and setters properly defined and the stored procedure has a total of 5 output parameters matching the attributes of `TicketInfo`.

Furthermore, here is my repository interface:

```
public interface TicketInfoRepository extends CrudRepository<TicketInfo, Long> {
    @Transactional(timeout = 5)
    @Procedure
    TicketInfo getTicket(Integer sys_id_game);
}
```

Also, here is my `context.xml` file (for Spring):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ar.com.boldt.godzilla" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="xx.xxx.xxx.godzilla.business.dao" />

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="${dataSource.show.sql}" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="xx.xxx.xxx.godzilla.business.dao" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ehcache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And finally a watered-down version of the stored procedure itself:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Terminal_GetTicket](
 @arg int 
,@res int output
,@res2 int output
)
as
Declare @error int

select 0, 1, 2

RETURN @error
```

Now, whenever I try setting the `@Autowired` annotation, I get the exception mentioned above.

Comment: I've never done this before, but I have the following two guesses (based on this link [1]: It seems that you can either set the name of the stored procedure explicitly by setting @Procedure(name="TicketInfo.getTicket") or you can align the procedureName with the name of your method (Terminal_GetTicket vs getTicket) [1] https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/jpa21

Comment: I changed my code as you suggested, I used @Procedure(name = "TicketInfo.getTicket") , but I get the same error.

Answer (score 9):

I remember that I have been struggling with the MS SQL stored procedures and spring-data-jpa. This is how I have been able to successfully run it:

Model:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
            name = "yourInternalName",
            query = "EXEC [procedure_name] :param1, :param2",
            resultClass = Foo.class
    )
 })
 @Entity
 public class Foo{

     /* Fields, getters, setters*/
}
```

That's pretty straightforward. This approach is different though, you are not declaring procedures directly (that's also the reason why it doesn't have to work if you decide to change RDBS).

Then you have to extend your repository:

```
public interface FooRepositoryCustom {

     Foo fancyMethodName(arg1, arg2);
}
```

And directly implement it:

```
public class FooRepositoryImpl implements FooRepositoryCustom {


@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public Foo fancyMethodName(arg1, arg2) {

    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("yourInternalName");
    query.setParameter("param1", arg1);
    query.setParameter("param2", arg2);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Let's put it all together:

```
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long>, FooRepositoryCustom {

}
```

Note that if you decide to return for example a List of `Foo` objects you only edit return value in your custom repository.

Comment: This solution works, however I change a little bit about the structure like this article
https://medium.com/@senanayake.kalpa/calling-stored-procedure-using-spring-jpa-ee37fa58ca2d

Answer (score 6):

I followed SirKometas advice but I could not get it to work so I came up with something that worked for me and I think from syntax point of view is better. First create your entity class like below.

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({//
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(//
            name = "MySP"//
            , procedureName = "my_sp"//
            , parameters = { //
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "arg", type = String.class)}//
            , resultClasses = Foo.class)//})
@Entity
public class Foo {
```

Then the Implementation class of the repository would be:

```
@Component
public class FooRepositoryImpl implements FooCustomRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Foo> foo(String arg) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("MySP");
        query.setParameter("arg", arg);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

The rest of the implementation is like the answer from SirKometa above. Think also that **you have to create a EntityManager bean in your application** for this to work.