# Stored Procedures with spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data

Having a stored procedure in Oracle which I need to call from a service in Java using Spring Data JPA.

Tested the procedure in sql developer and found to be working fine. It takes some 6 IN parameters and returns a ref_cursor.

Please help me on know how to execute this.

The Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_CONF(PROD_NAME IN VARCHAR2, DERIVATIVE IN VARCHAR2, PHY_SEC_SIZE IN VARCHAR2, PROD_CACH IN VARCHAR2, CAPACITY IN VARCHAR2,ENC_TYPE IN VARCHAR2, INTER_VAL IN VARCHAR2, HEADS IN VARCHAR2,DISCS IN VARCHAR2, AREALDENSITY IN VARCHAR2, DESIGNSITE IN VARCHAR2, RSLT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS ....
```

Here the first two parameters are mandatory fields in screen, so definitely it has value. But the other fields are optional.

The Spring data repository method is as below:

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "get_conf")
List<Object[]> testjpa(String prodName, String derivative, String phySize,
        String prodCache, String capacity, String encType,
        String interfaceVal, String heads, String discs,
        String arealDensity, String desingSite);
```

I have tried giving the return type as List and List. But nothing worked out.

If I am returning only one value, everything works fine. Problem comes in when I am returning multiple values and multiple rows.

The error that I am getting is as below
[image]

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612550/how-can-i-execute-a-stored-procedure-with-jpa-spring-data), but no luck.

Comment: Please post the code you tried and the error

Comment: Edited with Error and Spring data repository call

Comment: @AnithaRamaiah you should paste the complete stack trace. It's still not clear what caused the exception.

Comment: Also, please provide @NamedStoredProcedureQuery...

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Function**

```
PROCEDURE p_get_region_cur (v_out_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
        OPEN v_out_cur FOR SELECT region_id, region_name FROM regions;
END;
```

**Call from Java by using StoredProcedureQuery**

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("p_get_region_cur", Region.class);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
    List<Region> result = query.getResultList();
```