# To retrieve list of object from stored procedure SQL server through spring-jpa

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, spring-data-jpa

I wrote a stored procedure ,

`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCustomerSearch] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @clientNo varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT cs.* FROM [mm].[dbo].[CM_customerStatus] as cs  WHERE cs.[ClientNo] like @clientNo;
END`

I want to access that list of table records from spring JPA repository as List of object.Is there any way to do this task???

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your JPA repository and use [`EntityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) to run a stored procedure in spring data jpa. Use [`createNamedStoredProcedureQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedStoredProcedureQuery-java.lang.String-) to fire your stored procedure.

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("YOUR_PROCEDURE");
query.setParameter("arg", ARG);
query.getResultList();
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612550/how-can-i-execute-a-stored-procedure-with-jpa-spring-data) question for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I'll try on this

Comment: @Sudarshani Did it help?